# Accessing the Facebook signed_request parameter in iframe tab page

Tags: php, facebook, iframe

i was wondering how to access the Facebook signed_request parameter inside an iframe tab?

1. `$_REQUEST['signed_request']`
2. `$_POST['signed_request']`

Do I always get the signed_request? Or do I need to authorize the user first?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ohh the Facebook PHP SDK has a method for that (using $_REQUEST): $facebook->getSignedRequest()